# Reading YUY2 data from an IMFSample that appears to have improper data on Windows 10

Tags: h.264, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I am developing an application that using IMFSourceReader to read data from video files. I am using DXVA for improved performance. I am having trouble with one specific full-HD H.264 encoded AVI file. Based on my investigation this far, I believe that the IMFSample contains incorrect data. My workflow is below:

1. Create a source reader with a D3D manager to enable hardware acceleration.
2. Set the current media type to YUY2 as DXVA does not
   decode to any RGB colorspace.
3. Call ReadSample to get an IMFSample. Works fine.
4. Use the VideoProcessorBlt to perform YUY2 to BGRA32
   conversion. For this specific file it errors out with an
   E_INVALIDARGS error code. Decided to do the conversion myself.
5. Used IMFSample::ConvertToContiguousBuffer to receive an IMFMediaBuffer. When locking this buffer, the pitch is reported as 1280 bytes. This I believe is incorrect, because for a full HD video, the pitch should be (1920 + 960 + 960 = 3840 bytes).

I dumped the raw memory and extracted the Y, U and V components based on my understanding of the YUY2  layout. You can find it below. So, the data is there but I do not believe it is laid out as YUY2. Need some help in interpreting the data.

[image: Y component]

[image: U component]

[image: V component]
My code for reading is below:

```
    // Direct3D surface that stores the result of the YUV2RGB conversion
CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> _pTargetSurface;


IDirectXVideoAccelerationService* vidAccelService;
initVidAccelerator(&vidAccelService); // Omitting the code for this.

// Create a new surface for doing the color conversion, set it up to store X8R8G8B8 data.
hr = vidAccelService->CreateSurface( static_cast<UINT>( 1920 ),
                                     static_cast<UINT>( 1080 ),
                                     0,                                    // no back buffers
                                     D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,                 // data format
                                     D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,                      // default memory pool
                                     0,                                    // reserved
                                     DXVA2_VideoProcessorRenderTarget,     // to use with the Blit operation
                                     &_pTargetSurface,                     // surface used to store frame
                                     NULL);


GUID processorGUID;
DXVA2_VideoDesc videoDescriptor;
D3DFORMAT processorFmt;
UINT numSubStreams;

IDirectXVideoProcessor* _vpd;
initVideoProcessor(&vpd); // Omitting the code for this

// We get the videoProcessor parameters on creation, and fill up the videoProcessBltParams accordingly.
_vpd->GetCreationParameters(&processorGUID, &videoDescriptor, &processorFmt, &numSubStreams);

RECT targetRECT; // { 0, 0, width, height } as left, top, right, bottom
targetRECT.left = 0;
targetRECT.right = videoDescriptor.SampleWidth;
targetRECT.top = 0;
targetRECT.bottom = videoDescriptor.SampleHeight;
SIZE targetSIZE; // { width, height }
targetSIZE.cx = videoDescriptor.SampleWidth;
targetSIZE.cy = videoDescriptor.SampleHeight;

// Parameters that are required to use the video processor to perform 
// YUV2RGB and other video processing operations
DXVA2_VideoProcessBltParams _frameBltParams;

_frameBltParams.TargetRect = targetRECT;
_frameBltParams.ConstrictionSize = targetSIZE;
_frameBltParams.StreamingFlags = 0; // reserved.

_frameBltParams.BackgroundColor.Y = 0x0000;
_frameBltParams.BackgroundColor.Cb = 0x0000;
_frameBltParams.BackgroundColor.Cr = 0x0000;
_frameBltParams.BackgroundColor.Alpha = 0xFFFF;

// copy attributes from videoDescriptor obtained above.
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.VideoChromaSubsampling = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoChromaSubsampling;
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.NominalRange = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.NominalRange;
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.VideoTransferMatrix = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoTransferMatrix;
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.VideoLighting = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoLighting;
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.VideoPrimaries = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoPrimaries;
_frameBltParams.DestFormat.VideoTransferFunction = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoTransferFunction;

_frameBltParams.DestFormat.SampleFormat = DXVA2_SampleProgressiveFrame;

// The default values are used for all these parameters.
DXVA2_ValueRange pRangePABrightness;
_vpd->GetProcAmpRange(DXVA2_ProcAmp_Brightness, &pRangePABrightness);
DXVA2_ValueRange pRangePAContrast;
_vpd->GetProcAmpRange(DXVA2_ProcAmp_Contrast, &pRangePAContrast);
DXVA2_ValueRange pRangePAHue;
_vpd->GetProcAmpRange(DXVA2_ProcAmp_Hue, &pRangePAHue);
DXVA2_ValueRange pRangePASaturation;
_vpd->GetProcAmpRange(DXVA2_ProcAmp_Saturation, &pRangePASaturation);
_frameBltParams.ProcAmpValues = { pRangePABrightness.DefaultValue, pRangePAContrast.DefaultValue,
    pRangePAHue.DefaultValue, pRangePASaturation.DefaultValue };

_frameBltParams.Alpha = DXVA2_Fixed32OpaqueAlpha();
_frameBltParams.DestData = DXVA2_SampleData_TFF;

// Input video sample for the Blt operation
DXVA2_VideoSample _frameVideoSample;

_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.VideoChromaSubsampling = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoChromaSubsampling;
_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.NominalRange = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.NominalRange;
_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.VideoTransferMatrix = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoTransferMatrix;
_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.VideoLighting = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoLighting;
_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.VideoPrimaries = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoPrimaries;
_frameVideoSample.SampleFormat.VideoTransferFunction = videoDescriptor.SampleFormat.VideoTransferFunction;

_frameVideoSample.SrcRect = targetRECT;
_frameVideoSample.DstRect = targetRECT;
_frameVideoSample.PlanarAlpha = DXVA2_Fixed32OpaqueAlpha();
_frameVideoSample.SampleData = DXVA2_SampleData_TFF;


CComPtr<IMFSample> sample; // Assume that this was read in from a call to ReadSample

CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> buffer;
HRESULT hr = sample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &buffer);
CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9>  pSrcSurface;

// From the MediaBuffer, we get the Source Surface using MFGetService
hr = MFGetService( buffer, MR_BUFFER_SERVICE, __uuidof(IDirect3DSurface9), (void**)&pSrcSurface );

// Update the videoProcessBltParams with frame specific values.
LONGLONG sampleStartTime;
sample->GetSampleTime(&sampleStartTime);
_frameBltParams.TargetFrame = sampleStartTime;

LONGLONG sampleDuration;
sample->GetSampleDuration(&sampleDuration);

_frameVideoSample.Start = sampleStartTime;
_frameVideoSample.End = sampleStartTime + sampleDuration;
_frameVideoSample.SrcSurface = pSrcSurface;

// Run videoProcessBlt using the parameters setup (this is used for color conversion)
// The returned code is E_INVALIDARGS
hr = _vpd->VideoProcessBlt( _pTargetSurface,    // target surface
                            &_frameBltParams,   // parameters
                            &_frameVideoSample, // video sample structure
                            1,                      // one sample
                            NULL);                  // reserved
```

Comment: If your video is taken vertically then its dimensions would be 960x1920. The pitch is the actual width of the video plus extra padding bytes added to the width. In this case 1280 makes perfect sense as it is bigger than 960. Something else is causing VideoProcessorBlt to error out. Probably the parameters you set are wrong. Can you show us the code?

Comment: I inspected the rotation flags for this video and it says that the rotation angle is 0. Additionally, even if rotation of 90 was applied, for YUY2 I would assume that the pitch would be at least (1080 + 1080/2 + 1080/2 = 2160 bytes). I am adding code as requested.

Comment: Try to comment out the following two lines: _frameBltParams.TargetRect = targetRECT; _frameBltParams.ConstrictionSize = targetSIZE;

Comment: Didnt help. Am getting the same E_INVALIDARG error. 

On Windows 7, reading this file just crashes. 

Media Player is able to play the file OK on Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: The IMFMediaBuffer reports 1382400 bytes. With a pitch of 1280 bytes, that comes to (1382400/1280) 1080 lines which seems correct. As this is YUY2, this corresponds to 640 pixels of Y, 320 pixels of U and V each  along the row which is that the images represent.

Comment: Yes the pitch is correct. I don't see the values of "width" and "height", but I think you might have the source/dest rectangles wrong. You are creating a 1920x1080 target surface.

Comment: I set the source and destination rectangles to the dimensions of the video. This appears to work for all videos except this one. Is there a way for me determine what the src/dest rectangles should be? I am going to just hard-code the values for this file just to see if the Blt operation works.

Comment: I think the problem is that since the video is rotated (regardless of the missing MediaType attribute) the "height" that you provide for it is 1920 which is bigger than the 1080 value that you specify for the render target in CreateSurface call.

Comment: The issue appears to be that the IMFSample has a NV12 colorspace. If you look at the images, there appears to be chroma info at the bottom. This resembles an NV12 colorspace. I interpreted my dumped data as NV12 and I got a 1280x720 frame with perfect color. Here is the link: https://photos.app.goo.gl/dZefDkTsNQmWMw2D9

Comment: Changing the source rectangle to 1280x720 appears to have fixed the issue. The question now is how do I get this information?

Comment: You should be able to get that information from the IMFMEdiaType obtained via a call to GetCurrentMediaType of IMFSourceReader. Then query the MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE attribute.

Comment: After setting the current media type to YUY2 on the source, I queried the IMFMEdiaType from the source reader and queried frame size using MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE but it returned 1920x1080 not the decoded size of 1280x720.

Comment: obviously the sourcereader changes the media type. you should query the frame size after receiving the MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED flag in (On)ReadSample
you can also try GetNativeMediaType

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked like a charm. I was querying the media type after setting the CurrentMediaType and not after ReadSample. For every H.264 video that I have in my repo, the CurrentMediaTypeChanged flag is set on the first call to ReadSample but the videos were read fine without me having to take any action. I learnt something new today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a call to [ReadSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-readsample) of IMFSourceReader or inside [OnReadSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereadercallback-onreadsample) callback function of the IMFSourceReaderCallback implementation, you might receive the [MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/ne-mfreadwrite-mf_source_reader_flag) flag. It means that the current media type has changed for one or more streams. To get the current media type call the [IMFSourceReader::GetCurrentMediaType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-getcurrentmediatype) method. 
In your case you need to query (again) the IMFMediaType's [MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/mf-mt-frame-size-attribute) attribute for the video stream, in order to obtain the new correct video resolution. You should use the new video resolution to set the "width" and "height" values of the VideoProcessorBlt parameters' source and destination rectangles.